# Javascript version mismatch for Tabris framework

Tags: javascript, tabris, tabris-js

Few month ago I gave a try to [Tabris](https://tabris.com), a nice framework for the development of native Android and iOS apps in Javascript. I wanted to get back to it today but my test app has javascript version issues.

First, the QR code scanning on Tabris mobile app side failed with error `udefined`. I setup the IP address manually and the app got connected to the Tabris server running on my laptop. However, the console on the mobile app complains with: *Version mismatch: Javascript module "Tabris" (version 3.5.0) is incompatible with the native tabris platform (version 3.6.0).*.

I started by upgrading `tabris-cli` with `npm i -g tabris-cli`. It didn't help. Then I uninstalled and reinstalled both the mobile app and `tabris-cli`. Both are now in version `3.6.0` but the same error remains.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Version mismatch error stems from the fact that the native application code and the code of the JavaScript framework of your project are different.  If you look at the `package.json` file of the directory where you are running `tabris serve` it will probably have the tabris dependency set to 3.5.0

You can update it by running this command:

```sh
npm install tabris@3.6.0 --save
```